# Conditional Join Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am beginner with BigQuery and SQL in general. I have a query that looks like this:

```
    SELECT
      base.* 
      IF( regexp_contains(rate_name, 'usd'), price * ft.usd, IF(regexp_contains(rate_name, 'gbp'), price * ft.gbp, price )) AS converted_price
    FROM base_table base  
    JOIN 
      finance_table ft
    ON
      base.date = ft.date
```

In short, I have a table with some data (base) and depending on the currency that is the price, I want to convert using the rate stored in another table. The table with the rates (finance_table) has data only for 2021 but the base_table has data for dates before that.

What I want to do is to use this query as is when the date exists in the finance_table, otherwise use the rates from 2021-01-01 (this first date of finance_table).

What I tried is to join on this:

```
ON
    IF( ft.date IS NOT NULL, base.date = ft.date, ft.date = '2021-01-01')
```

However,  this doesn't give me any results when I query for a random date from 2020. I am sure that the condition is wrong, so any ideas?

P.S. Another thing that would suffice is using fixed numbers, e.g. if the date doesn't exist, multiply the price with 0.85 or 1.15, but this would probably make things more complicated.

EDIT:

Tables look like this:

BASE:

```
DATE      |   PRODUCT_NAME | PRICE | RATE_NAME
2020-01-01|   APPLE        | 0.5   |  usd
2021-01-01|   ORANGE       | 0.4   |  gbp
```

FINANCE_TABLE:

```
DATE      | USD   |  GBP
2021-01-01| 0.844 |  1.443
2021-01-02| 0.846 |  1.423
```

The final result should look like this, when I query for date = '2021-01-01'

```
DATE       | PRODUCT_NAME| PRICE | RATE_NAME | CONVERTED_PRICE
2021-01-01 | ORANGE      |  0.4  | gbp       | 0.5772
```

The problem lies  in the case where I query for dates that don't exist in the finance_table.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your `if()` expression seems unusual.  Where is the currency stored?

Comment: @GordonLinoff look at the edits. The currency is stored in finance_table.

Comment: . . No, the currency is stored in the base table.  The finance table has different columns for different currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two joins.  A direct translation into your query is:

```
SELECT price 
       (CASE WHEN base.rate_name = 'usd' 
             THEN base.price * coalesce(ft.usd, ft1.usd)
             WHEN base.rage_name = 'gbp'
             THEN base.price * coalesce(ft.gbp, ft.gbp)
             ELSE base.price
        END) AS converted_price
FROM base_table base LEFT JOIN
     finance_table ft
     ON base.date = ft.date JOIN
     finance_table ft1
     ON ft1.date = DATE '2020-01-01';
```

Comment: CROSS JOINS are not followed by ON clauses, but it if I use a LEFT join instead of a CROSS then it kinda does the job.  Thanks